# Select the element that called the jQuery function with onclick=""

Tags: jquery, onclick, element

I want to select the element that called the jQuery function. I think this should be working, but it's not.

The element:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$.myFunction(this)">link</a>
```

The function:

```
(function ($) {
    $.myFunction = function (element) {
        element.hide()
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` is the DOM node, so try with

```
$(element).hide()
```

As a sidenote avoid if possible to use inline handlers since they will make your code soon or later messy and unmantainable: if you are in control of the code you could write instead

```
<a href="#" class="someclass">link</a>
```

and

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', 'a.someclass', function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

using a cleaner event delegation

Comment: Thanks, why should avoid inline handlers?

Comment: I wrote it in my answer :) besides, the quality perceived from a page that is mixing javascript and markup is generally very low (if web development is a business for you, you should consider this carefully)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

html:

```
<a href="#" class="myclass">link</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.myclass').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to do it using the onclick=""

Comment: why would you like to use onclick?